# After Readed Barcode is not Opened ViewController Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

I've created one storyboard with name Main1.storyboard and this storyboard have backend file with ViewController.swift name. All projects im created with Swift 3.0 . This storyboard is for reading barcode, i want to make after reading barcode to open homeViewController.xib - homeViewController.swift file and to send this barcode result. HomeViewController class have Webview components. For me is important just to open homeViewController.xib - homeViewController.swift file after reading barcode and send barcode result. My homeViewController.swift and ViewController.swift class is as given bellow:

**homeViewController.swift:**

```
    import UIKit
    import SystemConfiguration
    import DrawerController
    import SVProgressHUD

    class homeViewController: UIViewController , UIWebViewDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var webView: UIWebView!
    var text:String = "http://www.google.com"
    var barcode:String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // setup title
        self.title = "My App"

        // setup NavigationBar Color
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = navigationBarColor


        let ud: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let data: NSData? = ud.object(forKey: "cookie") as? NSData
        if let cookie = data {
            let datas: NSArray? = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: cookie as Data) as? NSArray
            if let cookies = datas {
                for c in cookies as! [HTTPCookie] {
                    HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(c)
                }
            }
        }


        // setup side Bar
        if(sideBarPosition == "left"){
        self.setupLeftMenuButton()
        }
        else{
            self.setupRightMenuButton()
        }

        // setup WebView
        webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height-64))
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.delegate = self
        webView.scrollView.delegate = self
        webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        SVProgressHUD.show()
        if (typeOfData == "html"){
            // load from html file
            let myfile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: nameFileHtml, withExtension: "html")
            let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url: myfile!)
            webView.loadRequest(requestObj as URLRequest)
        }
        else{
            // load website data
            if(connectedToNetwork() == false){
                SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "No Internet Connection")
            }
            else{
                webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: text)!))
            }
        }


    }








    // setup left menu button icon
    func setupLeftMenuButton() {
        let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "menuleft.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(leftDrawerButtonPress), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 17) //CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
        button.imageView?.tintColor = iconColor
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
    }

    // setup left menu button action
    func leftDrawerButtonPress(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        self.evo_drawerController?.toggleDrawerSide(.left, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // setup right menu button icon
    func setupRightMenuButton() {
        let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "menuright.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(rightDrawerButtonPress), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 17) //CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
        button.imageView?.tintColor = iconColor
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
    }

    // setup right menu button action
    func rightDrawerButtonPress(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        self.evo_drawerController?.toggleDrawerSide(.right, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    // setup webView option
    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
    {
        SVProgressHUD.show()
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
    {
        if( barcode  != "")

        {
            self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from:
                "var element = document.getElementById('input-password');"
                + "element.value ="+barcode+";" +
                "")

        }

        let cookieJar: HTTPCookieStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
        let data: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: cookieJar.cookies) as NSData
        let ud: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        ud.set(data, forKey: "cookie")

     SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
     webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true




        let aLabel = UIButton()

        self.view.addSubview(aLabel)




        aLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
        aLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 123.0).isActive = true

        aLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "photo-camera.png"), for: .normal)
        aLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: aLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: aLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
     aLabel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()


    }

    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {


        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main1", bundle: nil)
        let balanceViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "barcode") as! ViewController
        self.present(balanceViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func btnclicked(sender: UIButton!)
    {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "unwraped.stringValue", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0){
            self.webView.reload()
        }
    }

    // check connection
    func connectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, $0)
            }
        }) else {
            return false
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
            return false
        }

        let isReachable = flags.contains(.reachable)
        let needsConnection = flags.contains(.connectionRequired)

        return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
    import UIKit
    import AVFoundation

    class ViewController: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate , UIWebViewDelegate , AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var viewPreview: UIView!
        var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
        var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
        var isReading: Bool = false
        var barcoderesult:String=""
        @IBOutlet weak var anulo_btn: UIButton!

    @IBAction func bnt_cancel(_ sender: Any) {





        let vc = homeViewController(nibName: "homeViewController", bundle: nil)




        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

        self.evo_drawerController?.setCenter(navigationController, withCloseAnimation: true, completion: nil)


        self.dismiss(animated: true)


    }
    // setup left menu button icon
    func setupLeftMenuButton() {
        let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "menuleft.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(leftDrawerButtonPress), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 17) //CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
        button.imageView?.tintColor = iconColor
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
    }

    // setup left menu button action
    func leftDrawerButtonPress(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        self.evo_drawerController?.toggleDrawerSide(.left, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    // MARK: - View Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = navigationBarColor

        // setup title

      setupLeftMenuButton()




        viewPreview.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

        captureSession = nil;

        if !isReading {
            if (self.startReading()) {
            }
        }
        else {
            stopReading()
         }
        isReading = !isReading



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - IBAction Method

    @IBAction func startStopClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if !isReading {
            if (self.startReading()) {
            }
        }
        else {
            stopReading()
        }
        isReading = !isReading


    }

    // MARK: - Custom Method
    func startReading() -> Bool {
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
            captureSession?.addInput(input)
            // Do the rest of your work...
        } catch let error as NSError {
            // Handle any errors
            print(error)
            return false
        }

        videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        videoPreviewLayer.frame = viewPreview.layer.bounds
        viewPreview.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer)

        /* Check for metadata */
        let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)
        captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = captureMetadataOutput.availableMetadataObjectTypes
        print(captureMetadataOutput.availableMetadataObjectTypes)
        captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        captureSession?.startRunning()

        return true
    }
    func stopReading() {
        captureSession?.stopRunning()
        captureSession = nil
        videoPreviewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()

    }



    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        for data in metadataObjects {
            let metaData = data as! AVMetadataObject
            print(metaData.description)
            let transformed = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metaData) as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            if let unwraped = transformed {
                print(unwraped.stringValue)
            //    lblString.text = unwraped.stringValue
            //    btnStartStop.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
                barcoderesult = unwraped.stringValue

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: unwraped.stringValue, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)






                self.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(stopReading), with: nil, waitUntilDone: false)
                isReading = false;







            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer your question without providing the error you gets when you run or what kind of error is listed in the console.

BTW, i guess you may haven't set the identifier for the viewController in each storyboards.

Comment: If a question is difficult to answer, it should closed, not answered.